# Есть ли возможность добавить элемент в массив c++?

Tags: c++, массивы

Есть ли какая нибудь возможность добавить в конец встроенного массива `c++` элемент? Т. е. аналог функции `push_back` для `std::vector`?

Comment: Если позволяет выделенная память - да. Для этого вам надо хранить количество уже добавленных в массив элементов (итератор на последний добавленный элемент).

Comment: @DmitryK а как это будет выглядеть в коде?

Comment: если массив будете заворачивать в класс...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если позволяет выделенная память - да.
Если вы реализуете концепцию отличия выделенной памяти для хранения от количества помещенных в массив объектов. Для этого вам надо хранить количество уже добавленных в массив элементов (итератор на последний добавленный элемент).
Или просто обернете свой массив в обертку `std::Array<>`. :)
А реализуется просто. При объявлении массива, вы считаете, что просто выделили память под это количество элементов, а сами элементы добавляете в массив только с помощью специальных функций. Естественно лучше это сделать с помощью класса. Но можно и на голом `c`

```
int MyArray[100]; // считаете, что это не массив из 100 элементов, а выделенная под 100 элементов память.
int MyArrayCount = 0; // счетчик количества элементов в массиве

// функции добавления/удаления элементов в массив
void push_back(int x)
{
    MyArray[MyArrayCount] = x;
    ++MyArrayCount;
}
```

Можете сами обертку написать - она не сложная. Можете использовать уже написанную `std::Array<>`.
Если не заморачиваться с владением объектом (выделением/удалением памяти), то обертка простенькая (проверять выход за пределы массива или нет - сами решаете)

```
class MyArray
{
   int* const mas;
   const size_t capacity;
   size_t size;

public:
   MyArray(int* _mas, size_t _capacity): 
        mas(_mas), capacity (_capacity), size(0) {}

   // далее все нужные функции
   void push_back(int x)
   {
       mas[size] = x;
       ++size;
   }
   int& back(void) { return mas[size]; }
   void pop_back() { --size; } 

   int& operator[](size_t ind);
   int& at(size_t ind);
   size_t size();
   bool empty();
}

int main()
{
    const int s = 100;
    int a[s];

    MyArray arr(a, s);

    arr.push_back(0);
}
```

Comment: А Вы обратили внимание на то, про какой массив он спрашивает?

Answer (score -1):

Любое добавление элемента меняет количество элементов. А массив с переменным количеством элементов не просто так называется **динамическим**: это намёк на то, в какой памяти его следует создавать. И не надо кивать на бейсик, там любой DIM – операция, а не декларация, а задание размера массива операцией уже делает его динамическим.